# Confused regarding the Gram-Schmidt Theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I'm given the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as $$\langle (x_1,x_2,x_3), (x_1,x_2,x_3)\rangle=x_1^2+2x_2x_1+2x_2^2+x_3^2$$

Let $B=\{ v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $v_1=(-1,1,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,0)$, $v_3=(1,0,1)$. Applying the Gram Schmidt theorem to $B$ yields an orthogonal basis $\{ u_1,u_2,u_3\}$. I'm asked to find the coordinates of $u_3$ in the canonical basis, and I'm getting $$u_3=\Big(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)$$, yet the correct answer supposedly is $$u_3=\Big( 0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)$$I've checked multiple times yet I keep getting the same result and I'm starting to wonder if the teacher made a mistake. Is the teacher's answer correct?

Comment: What do you have as $u_1$ and $u_2$? Also, do you want just an orthogonal basis, or an orthonormal (all length 1) one?

Comment: That is not a scalar product. And what is the canonical basis of a *vector*?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, I meant to say "the coordinates of $u_3$ in the canonical basis". Also, why is it not an inner product?

Comment: Because an inner product in $\Bbb R^3$ is a bilinear map from $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R$ for which certain conditions hold. The definition of your map uses $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ twice.

Comment: I believe it does define an inner product. You can use some polarization identity for this. You for example have (in general) $\langle x,y\rangle = \frac12(\langle x+y,x+y\rangle - \langle x,x\rangle - \langle y,y\rangle)$ where $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

Comment: @Rik93 yes, that's probably what my teacher meant. Also, he is only asking for an orthogonal basis.

Comment: In that case, answers can be different by a constant multiple. However, you also have a minus sign extra. Have you checked whether your vectors (or those given by your teacher) are orthogonal?